# Replace NULLs with value if the value exists for the same ID in Groovy

Tags: groovy

if I have an ArrayList that looks like:

```
[10aBl,NULL,06/02/2104]
[10aBl,100,12/12/2016]
[cs30h,845,13/07/2017]
[cs30h,845,17/09/2017]
[cs30h,NULL,01/02/2013]
```

How do I replace the NULLs in column 2 with the existing values from column 2 that match the id (column 1) i.e.

```
[10aBl,100,06/02/2104]
[10aBl,100,12/12/2016]
[cs30h,845,13/07/2017]
[cs30h,845,17/09/2017]
[cs30h,845,01/02/2013]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far and how has it failed?

Answer (score 0):

a 2 min solution would be

```
def a = [ '10aBl,NULL,06/02/2104', '10aBl,100,12/12/2016', 'cs30h,845,13/07/2017','cs30h,845,17/09/2017','cs30h,NULL,01/02/2013' ].collect{ it.split(',') }

def replacements = a.collectEntries{ 'NULL' != it[ 1 ] ? it[ 0..1 ] : [:] }
a.each{ if( 'NULL' == it[ 1 ] ) it[ 1 ] = replacements[ it[ 0 ] ] }

assert '[[10aBl, 100, 06/02/2104], [10aBl, 100, 12/12/2016], [cs30h, 845, 13/07/2017], [cs30h, 845, 17/09/2017], [cs30h, 845, 01/02/2013]]' == a.toString()
```